# How to handle nth-child for internet explorer 8

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have a php script that calls a series of images that display as so:

[image]

This is the php code that calls them:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT
parent_business_id,
image_url,
alt_tag,
description,
thumb_url,
business
FROM
images
ORDER BY
RAND()
LIMIT
6
";

$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
or die (mysql_error($dbc));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$parent = $row["parent_business_id"];
$image = $row["image_url"];
$alt = $row["alt_tag"];
$description = $row["description"];
$thumb = $row["thumb_url"];
$business = $row["business"];

$mainthumb = "./images/270x270/$image.jpg";

echo

"<div class='gallery_image_container'>

<a href='business-profile.php?business_id=$parent' class='gallery_darken'><img src='$mainthumb' alt='$alt' title='$description' /></a>

</div>";

}

?>
```

At the moment I am using css3's nth-child to add margins to the central images:

```
div.gallery_image_container:nth-child(3n+2){
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

The problem I have is this works great in browsers that support css3 but ie 7 and ie 8 will not and I need a solution. I am thinking that maybe I can do this by adding classes in php. If so which function would I use. Is there an nth-child like selector in php?

Comment: PHP doesn't really have an nth-child selector, but you can do it yourself, as you loop through to print them out, if it is the 2nd item, 5th item, etc, just add the class.

Comment: off topic, but worth mentioning: `ORDER BY RAND()` is an extremely slow way of doing a query. It basically has to load the whole table. It's fine for small tables, but if you've got a lot of data in there, `ORDER BY RAND()` will give you really bad performance issues.

Comment: also off topic, but *definitely* worth mentioning: The `mysql_xxx()` functions in PHP are deprecated. This means that PHP is dropping support for them and may remove them from the language entirely in future versions. In any case, regardless of that, they've been considered obsolete and insecure for a long time. It is *strongly* recommended to switch to using one of the better mysql APIs provided by PHP, either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @SDC The table is relatively small so I'm not too worried about performance issues. If there is a better way however, I am open to suggestions. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @SDC The depecated functions is an issue. I will have to look into this. I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to mysql and php. Will it be a painful switch?

Comment: @RichardBell - re `ORDER BY RAND()`: if it's a small table, and if you are sure it will remain small, then stick with what you have. If it's going to be bigger, or if you have other tables you want to order randomly that will be big, there are other techniques that work better. There are several options, and I know there are answers on this site that detail them, so do a bit of searching if you need to.

Comment: @RichardBell - re the deprecated functions. The PHP manual has details. Of the other options, `mysqli` is pretty similar to `mysql`; generally not too much hassle to switch. PDO is more powerful but the syntax is quite different, so might take a bit more effort but is worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy mentioned in the comments you can find out to which elements you have to add a class with PHP. All you need is a modulo division.

A pure CSS-Solution requires you to improve your HTML. It is obviously a list of images, therefore: Use a list. The resulting HTML should look something like this:

```
<ul class="gallery_container">
    <li>
        <a href='business-profile.php?business_id=$parent' class='gallery_darken'><img src='$mainthumb' alt='$alt' title='$description' /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='business-profile.php?business_id=$parent' class='gallery_darken'><img src='$mainthumb' alt='$alt' title='$description' /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='business-profile.php?business_id=$parent' class='gallery_darken'><img src='$mainthumb' alt='$alt' title='$description' /></a>
    </li>
    […]
</ul>
```

In the CSS now remove your :nth-child rule and instead add the following two rules:

```
.gallery_container {
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.gallery_container > li {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution dave. Thank you very much. You were right with 10px before you edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS selectors like `nth-child` that aren't supported in IE8, my suggestion is to use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Selectivizr is a Javascript library that back-ports a whole range of CSS selectors into old versions of IE, so that your standard CSS code can work unchanged across all browsers.

The other alternative is an older script called [ie7.js](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html) (and its later versions ie8.js and ie9.js), which also does the same sort of thing, plus fixing a load of other bugs and quirks in IE. But my preference would be for Selectivizr, as it's much more targetted (ie it doesn't do as much as ie7.js), and its much newer code, both of which ought to mean it performs better.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
$(identifier:nth-child(3n+2)').addClass('styleClassName');
```

using jQuery

Comment: I don't think posting a Javascript solution is of any help here. Especially if it depends on a framework. This can (and should) be done with CSS, or, if there is no other way, with PHP.